# Function returns no value

Tags: python, csv

When I define a function, it returns no value. However, I've verified the code of the function alone in IDLE,and it works. Where is the problem? The file truly contains the value I want to get. When I use debugger, step this function, it jumps from 'for row in reader:' directly to the end. Where is my problem? My code:

```
import re,csv

F=open('file.csv')

# `......`

def prog_rownum(Ref,s):

    P=[]
    reader=csv.reader(s)
    for row in reader:
        m=re.match(Ref,','.join(row))
        if m:
            P.append(reader.line_num)
    return P
# `......`

P1=prog_rownum('U16',F)

# `......`
```

The data (colnum A-C) in file is in this way, sorry for the unspecific information:

```
InstPin       Netlist   RefDes

U16:0:NMI       0   U16

U16:0:O\E\      0   U16

U16:0:R\S\T\    0   U16

U16:0:REF_FREQ  0   U16

U16:0:REFCLK_C  0   U16

U16:0:REFCLK_N  0   U16

U16:0:REFCLK_P  0   U16

U16:0:RX_N0     0   U16

U16:0:RX_N1     0   U16

U16:0:RX_N10    0   U16

U16:0:RX_N11    0   U16

U16:0:RX_N12    0   U16

U16:0:RX_N13    0   U16
```

I just want to return the needed rownum which contains the information I need.

Comment: How do you know it returns no value? Give us something we can reproduce, at minimum by including sample data that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Did you try: `print P1`

Comment: Are you sure your indents are correct? Especially no mixture of tabs and spaces? (If the return line has a different kind of indent to the rest, it might not be associated with the right block)

Comment: your code is working for me, but you are splitting in rows with the reader and then joining back again to check for value, see my answer for a cleaner method.

Comment: @agf, the wrong shows:                                               File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python\nets.py", line 34, in <module>
    P1_start=int(P1[0])
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to say without more details but the following does the same as your function and is cleaner, may be it solves your problem:

```
def prog_rownum(filename, ref):
    """ Return a list with the line numbers where ref appears in filename """
    with open(filename) as f:
        return [line_num for line_num, line in enumerate(f) 
                if line.startswith(ref)]    # alternatively "if ref in line" checks anywhere
```

Test it with

```
>>> print prog_rownum('file.csv', 'U16')
[2, 5, 7]
```

Comment: You pass a `filename` variable you don't use, and I don't believe your output -- lists in Python look like `[2, 5, 7]`, not `[2 ,5 ,7]`.

Comment: @DSM, fixed, the output was made up because at that moment the OP had not provided a test file.

Comment: @elyase, sorry, In my code, s stands for the opened file, what's the s means in your function code?

Comment: @elyase, is it necessary to reopen the file inside the function which is opened as F in my code? Beside, in the csv file, the data I showed is in the middle place of the file, so I alternatively try your comment like this:`def prog_rownum(ref,s):`                `return [line_num for line_num, line in enumerate(s) if ref in line] `      Do i use in correct way?Because I still get no value..

Comment: @smallsu, 1-the function opens the file and analyzes it and the `with` takes care of closing the file properly

Comment: @smallsu, my comment was referring to the position of the string inside the line, ex: if the `ref` is not at the beginning but somewhere else in the line.

Comment: @smallsu, did you do `print prog_rownum('file.csv', 'U16')` and you get no value?

Comment: @elyase, I just put the return value into a list, finally it works, thank you so much for your kind help and others' kind suggestions. There is much for me a beginner to learn. And why my own less advanced code of the function did't work still confuses me.